# Rails - Stripe integration for subscription at org level based on user activity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm trying to figure out how to integrate stripe into my Rails 4 app.

My pricing model is that organisations pay, each month, based on how many users are on the platform and they also pay success fees based on how many of their own users achieved success in that month. So there is a flat fee plus a variable fee based on each organisation's users plus each of the organisations user's activity in the month.

I have models for User, Organisation, Plan, Subscription (join table between plan and organisation)

I'm trying to figure out how to set this up in Stripe.

I want to add :quantity to Plan so that each subscription is the amount multiplied by the quantity where the quantity is equal to the number of users that belong to an organisation. I then want to add discretionary charges based on success fees for each user in that organisation in that month.

I currently have these models:

```
Plan.rb
    stripe_id:string \
    name:string \
    description:text \
    amount:integer \
    interval:string \
    published:boolean

Subscription.rb
    organisation:references \
    plan:references \
```

If I add :quantity to plan and write a method on Plan to calculate the number of users at each end of month, will that give me the base charge? Do I then need another model that lets me charge the success fee?

Comment: Are the success fees incurred at the time of monthly billing?  Basically, are all of these charges being rolled together and billed to the customer as one subscription fee or are you looking to send multiple charges in addition to the subscription fee each month at different times?

Comment: @bkunzi01- each month, I want to send an invoice for the base subscription fee plus the success fees accrued in the month. 1 invoice per organisation per month

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the ["metered billing"](https://support.stripe.com/questions/metered-subscription-billing) support article.

Basically, you could do something like this:

- [create one or more plans](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_plan) with the amount you want (e.g. $10/month)
- [create subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription) to these plans, with the appropriate `quantity`
- set up a [webhook endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) to receive [`invoice.created`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types-invoice.created) events
- each time you receive an `invoice.created` event on your server, [create invoice items](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_invoiceitem) for the success fees

Approximately one hour after the `invoice.created` event, the invoice will be closed and payment will be attempted.

Comment: Thanks Ywain. Does that mean that I have two separate billing protocols in Stripe - 1 for the subscription fee and another for the success fees, with the success fees being invoiced on success and the subscription fees being issued periodically?

Comment: I have a model called stripe_webhook.rb, I add Stripe::InvoiceItem.create(
    :customer => "xxxxxx",
    :amount => 1000,
    :currency => "aud",
    :description => "Success fee"
).  Is that it? I'm confused about how this will work when I will create an invoice for success fees on success. Ideally, I want to add that success fee to the amount that will be billed when the monthly subscription fee is invoiced, but this looks like it sends after an hour. Am I reading the documents correctly?